# R section not working

Tags: javascript, java, r, rstudio, qapplication

If i open the R section its shows the `Javascript Alert - 127.0.0.1` box likes this,

```
<p>R encountered a fatal error.</p>The session was terminated.
```

In the terminal its shows,

```
aarthika@aarthika-HP-406-G1-MT:~$ rstudio
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x23d2280, glyph=2797
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x23d2280, glyph=2797
QIODevice::read: device not open
QIODevice::read: device not open
QIODevice::read: device not open
QIODevice::read: device not open
QIODevice::read: device not open
QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Given that no one has answered in an hour, I would wager a bet that not everyone is clear on what "open the R section" means. This seems like a good place where we could start deciphering the question.

Comment: In my system i have r and rstudio. If i open the rstudio it shows like that...

Comment: Have you compiled R by hand? Perhaps [this thread](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207573157-RStudio-white-window) could be of some use?

Comment: I'm not very versed in OSX (not at all), but after searching the internet a bit and judging by the comments it would appear a corrupt installation could be the culprit. Perhaps you don't have write permission to all the folders?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I do not know if you use also Rstudio, I guess for me the latter was the problem, but not quite sure. What I did is I completely uninstalled both R and R Studio, deleted all the supporting files that are connected with both programs (search your computer!), restart the computer (!) and uploaded both again and it functioned. Hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the very same error:

```
Javascript Alert - 127.0.0.1
```

Instead of debugging the problem I simply uninstalled both R and RStudio and reinstalled them and it worked. Please uninstall and reinstall and check if it works for you too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue a couple of weeks ago, and for the first time since I use Rstudio: many years either on OSX or windows.
The same question as been posted many times but I never found any satisfying solution.
I noticed that everything worked fine when I uninstalled Rstudio, removed the RStudio-Desktop folder from %LOCALAPPDATA% (on windows), and reinstalled a fresh version.
However, I got the same alert, again, after reopening sessions... Clearly, something goes wrong when RStudio tries to open a session by using some settings, stored from previous ones...
I finally suppressed the RStudio-Desktop folder, reinstalled RStudio, and unchecked everything but 'Use debug error handler...' and 'Automatically notify me...' in 'global options' -> 'General settings'. So, no Re-use, Restore or Save.
I'm not able to provide any explanation, sorry about that, but everything works just fine now !

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by completely uninstalling R and Rstudio and installing them again from the beginning.